# What to keep as the cyber duck connection server endpoint URL in IBM-Cloud-cloud object storage

Tags: websphere, ibm-cloud, object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

What to keep as the cyber duck connection server endpoint URL in IBM-Cloud-cloud object storage?
[My buckets details (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3gxY.png)
You can see my location in **au-syd**

[My Cyberduck open connection prompt(Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGpja.png)

What endpoint should I keep??
If i hve done ay mistake pls correct me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your Cyberduck version needs an update.  I'm on version 7.10.0 (35184), which is current.  I see an option for Server -- that's where you put your IBM endpoint.  I used the public endpoint and it connects just fine, even to private-only buckets.

Try it like this:

[image: Cyberduck Connection Settings]

Comment: Hi Rob, Thanks a lot for your reply, But I checked my version number,Pls check the Imgur link https://i.imgur.com/WlMoq2x.png